# converting a batch file to shell script (multiple jars on Mac)

Tags: shell, batch-file

My shell scripting knowledge is minimal. So I'm trying to convert the following:

```
@set CLASSPATH=".;.\resources\;.\lib\jboss-client.jar;.\lib\jfxtras-labs-2.2-  r4.jar;.\lib\jfxrt.jar;.\lib\icecile.jar;"

echo CLASSPATH: %CLASSPATH%
".\jre7\bin\java" -classpath %CLASSPATH% com.ent.thing.icecile.ui.icecile
```

so this is what I wrote

```
#!/bin/sh

export CLASSPATH=/resources:/lib/jboss-client.jar:/lib/jfxtras-labs-2-r4.jar:/lib/jfxrt.jar:/lib/icecile.jar

echo CLASSPATH: $CLASSPATH
"java" -classpath $CLASSPATH com.ent.thing.icecile.ui.icecile
```

Im using a Mac computer and I've been glossing over some documentation but this doesn't want to run for me. Any help would be great

Comment: What is the error please?

Comment: Cannot find main class. Does this structurally look correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I can see wrong with your script is that, you're using absolute paths in your classpath. While this is not wrong, I doubt it is what you want. So, using relative paths (`./`) instead of absolute path (`/`), should solve one of your problems.

Try:

```
#!/bin/sh

# You don't need to 'export' unless you want the variable to exist
# outside of your script
CLASSPATH=".:./resources:./lib/jboss-client.jar:./lib/jfxtras-labs-2-r4.jar:./lib/jfxrt.jar:./lib/icecile.jar"

echo CLASSPATH:$CLASSPATH
java -classpath $CLASSPATH com.ent.thing.icecile.ui.icecile
```

Comment: this did the trick for me. Could you possibly tell me what the echo CLASSPATH:$CLASSPATH actually does? I had to transfer this but my scripting skills are beginner level.

Comment: @Joshhw - it displays the word CLASSPATH, followed by a colon, followed by the contents of the variable $CLASSPATH.

Comment: `echo` in shell is just like `echo` in batch scripts or `print` in other languages, and it's mostly used so the programmer can see what is going on. That line is basically saying, print out the literal **CLASSPATH:** followed by the value in my `CLASSPATH` variable